# Why Does OnChange Event of Parent window textbox when called from child window not working

Tags: javascript

**Below code gives error on child window**

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(txtSTAmount).onchange()
```

**below code works on parent window**

```
document.getElementById(txtSTAmount).onchange()
```

- txtSTAmount is a variable containing an element ID
- URL are "Web\Find\Find_Tax.aspx" child window and "Web\A1007_Modify.aspx" parent window

***Why Does OnChange Event of Parent window textbox when called from child window not working?***

> **Found Solution : window.opener.document.getElementById(txtSTAmount).onchange(this.event)**

just found that error was due to validator on textbox not getting event object :)

Comment: Could this be due to the same origin policy ?

Comment: Can you show us the complete URL of both windows ?

Comment: Ok. Time to ask. How does it not work? (sorry for not asking before)

Comment: These are not the URLs, these are the paths ? Can't you show use the full URL, including the protocol and domain (e.g http://example.com/web/find/df.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If txtSTAmount is a variable (as is seems) containing an element ID, and not an element ID (it has no quotes), then the variable is defined in parent windows but not in child window. Define and initialize it to a correct value.

If txtSTAmount is an element id, call your function as

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('txtSTAmount').onchange()
```

Comment: txtSTAmount is a variable containing an element ID

Comment: In parent window, txtSTAmount is a variable containing and element ID. So the call works. Is it the same on child window?

Comment: Yes, I have set value from child window similarly window.opener.document.getElementById(txtSTAmount).value = "0";